# Page URL Modifications and Google response

Tags: seo, google, redirects, url

I need to change the address of one of the pages of my site.
I will create a new page with absolutely the same content and the same structure of the page (no changes to the content of the page at all, 100% copy), and then I will do 301 redirect from the old page to the new one.

So for example:
`example.com/somegoodpage` (the old page)
Will 301 redirect to:
`example.com/goodpage` (the new page, exactly the same as the old one, except the URL).

How will Google respond to this kind of URL change in terms of search result positions?

Maybe this shouldn't be done at all because Google does not like this kind of redirect and heavily punishes for it? If so, maybe there is another way to do this?

Comment: You will be fine as long as the redirect is set properly. I've done it several times myself.

Comment: Don't forget to change all the internal links on your site that point to that page.   They should all point to the new URL.

Answer (score 1):

301 is the right way of changing the URL. I've had to do this myself in the past.

If you search for "301 redirect pagerank", or similar terms, you will find many articles telling you that a 301 redirect does not cause you to loose your rank.
Most of these articles eventually refer to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/methode/status/757923179641839616) by Gary Ilyes, who works for Google. So, there is a (more or less) authorative source for this <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'd be delighted to hear about an official announcement on Google's own site, as those would be preferable to a Tweet.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and use a 301 redirect (passes 90-99% of link juice), make sure you update your sitemap (mention this page was modified in the date field).

On the next crawl it will be sorted. Until then, you will have your current page redirecting and passing on the juice of the link.